# jQuery data from .on method

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

I'm using the .on method because the html button i'm loading in is AJAX based. Why am I not getting the data? It returns un-defined.

```
var $content_details = $('.content_details'),
    thumb = $('button.thumbs');

$content_details.on('click', thumb, function(){

    alert( $(this).data('video') );
});

<button class="thumbs" data-video="1">Button</button>
```

Comment: The second argument to `on()` must be a selector (i.e. a string), not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the .on() method is incorrect. It should be a selector not a jQuery object.

```
$content_details.on('click', 'button.thumbs', function(){
    alert( $(this).data('video') );
});
```